# SharePoint CAML query Where clause Not Filtering

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to construct a CAML query for list item on SP2019 site. I have the below code returning the entire list. I read that if there is a issue in the query , all the items in the list are returned. Please advise.

```
            List dashboardList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Dashboard");
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            string searchfor = "CPPMC";
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name = 'Title'/><Value Type ='Text'>" + searchfor+ "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";
            ListItemCollection listItems = dashboardList.GetItems(camlQuery);
            context.Load(listItems);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (ListItem item in listItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}",item.Id,item["Title"], item["Processing_x0020_Date"]);
            }
```

Comment: Please, substitute <Eq> to <Contains> and check the result.

Answer (score 0):

**View** element is missing in CAML Query which you are using.

Try below code,

```
        List dashboardList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Dashboard");
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        string searchfor = "CPPMC";
        camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name = 'Title'/><Value Type ='Text'>" + searchfor+ "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
        ListItemCollection listItems = dashboardList.GetItems(camlQuery);
        context.Load(listItems);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (ListItem item in listItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}",item.Id,item["Title"], item["Processing_x0020_Date"]);
        }
```

If you are looking for exact search then you should use **Eq** or if you are looking for contains search then you should use **Contains** tag in your query.

**Official Documentation:**
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/view-schema